# How to read "local storage" of website with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

Is it possible to access the local storage of other websites with a different domain than the domain of the website that saved it, or is it restricted to a specific domain only?

Comment: If you plan to "share" local storage, then you already have the ability to just have a back-end db that is "shared". Furthermore, "local" storage is considered "private" to the user's browser. You could share it by sending whatever data is in it to a backend db, by why bother since you would have this data anyway before it ended up local storage to then send it to the backend db.

Comment: you can send localstorage data to your server in a json or something and send it to other clients as well to keep them in sync;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, the `localStorage` object is bound to the website origin, the origin being defined by the scheme (protocol, i.e. https), host (domain), and port.